# Pyspark sql query not working, problematic group by

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, hql

Im trying to get working  this code but when i transfer it from SAS to pyspark sql its not working. if i add a group by im some part it works but it gives me an empty table

The group by 1 after "Online" its what removes me the error but gives empty table.

```py
Online = spark.sql(
'''SELECT DISTINCT tAuxiliar.canalidad,
                CASE
                    WHEN tAuxiliar.percentil < 0.25 THEN "p25"
                    WHEN tAuxiliar.percentil >= 0.25
                         AND tAuxiliar.percentil < 0.50 THEN "p50"
                    WHEN tAuxiliar.percentil >= 0.50
                         AND tAuxiliar.percentil < 0.75 THEN "p75"
                END AS grupo,
                max(corte_max) AS percentil
FROM
  (SELECT "Online" AS canalidad,
          tPercen.percentil,
          min(tPercen.operaciones) AS corte_min,
          max(tPercen.operaciones) AS corte_max
   FROM
     (SELECT operaciones,
             percentile_approx(operaciones, 1) AS percentil
      FROM base_canalidad_unica
      WHERE canalidad = "Online"
      GROUP BY 1) AS tPercen
   GROUP BY 1,
            2) AS tAuxiliar
WHERE tAuxiliar.percentil < 0.75
GROUP BY 1,
         2''')
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute just one piece : `SELECT operaciones,
             percentile_approx(operaciones, 1) AS percentil
      FROM base_canalidad_unica
      WHERE canalidad = "Online"
      GROUP BY 1` to see if you have the correct results at least here.

Comment: yes, and it works, only that i tried with percentile instead of percentile_approx, i pasted the wrong query but the rest is the same. the group by 1 is not in the original query and that is getting me crazy

Comment: You rarely never need to do SELECT DISTINCT when you do GROUP BY. If it makes any result differences, you should take a second look at what you do.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do `group by 1, 2` in spark-sql. Instead of the numbers. specify the columns.